#  How to notify an user when he tries to close a tab or close the browser

Tags: silverlight

First of all, I always say the same: sorry about my english is very weak. I hope you can understand me well.

I need to notify an user when he tries to close a tab or close the browser.
Is there any way to fire an event to avoid the browser will be closed?
The application is made in silverlight.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292071/silverlight-stop-page-closing-before-being-saved  check this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the following example, there is also a sample application:

http://www.blog.jonnycornwell.com/2011/01/23/using-silverlight-and-javascript-to-prevent-leaving-a-webpage/

It's about using Silverlight and JavaScript to prevent leaving a webpage.

The javascript:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
window.onbeforeunload = askConfirm;
function askConfirm() {
    var control = document.getElementById("silverlightControl");
    var preventLeave = control.Content.Page.PreventLeave();
    if (!preventLeave) {
        return;
    }
    var message = control.Content.Page.LeaveRequested();
    return message;
}
</script>
```

The silverlight code:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject("Page", this);
}

[ScriptableMember]
public string LeaveRequested()
{
    return "You have unsaved changes to your current document?";
}

[ScriptableMember]
public bool PreventLeave()
{
    return (bool)PreventLeaveCheckBox.IsChecked;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the awnser it looks good but I always get a javasript error because document.getElementById("silverlightControl") = null I think I've forgotten something. Can anybody help me?

Comment: I solved it! I find document.getElementById("xxxx") name setting the id in the <div id="silverlightControlHost"> in the <object data="data:application/x-silverlight ...

Comment: @Mirlo You had to change "silverlightControl" to your control name

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily with javascript. For example:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        function closeIt(url,name)
        {
            return "Hi there! I'm a message!";
        }
        window.onbeforeunload = closeIt;
    // -->
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <p>I'm a webpage!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```